# number of nodes for a level in a first child - next sibling tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, n-ary-tree

I have to write a function to find the number of nodes in a level of a first child - next sibling N-ary tree.
My function is:

```
int nodesAtLevel(NTree root, int level) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (level == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return nodesAtLevel(root->firstChild, level - 1) + 
           nodesAtLevel(root->nextSibling, level - 1);
}
```

but it does not work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: *but it does not work* How should it work?How is it not working?

Comment: Can you explain why you are decrementing `level` when calculating the number of nodes associated with `nextSibling`?

Comment: The structure of your tree is unclear. This is an n-ary tree? So not only does a node have children it has siblings? And if that's the case, then `if(level == 0) { return 1; }` wouldn't be correct. What if the current level has siblings? The answer would not then be 1. If you haven't done so, draw yourself a picture of the tree structure and use it as a guide to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code seems to only return 2. I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
int nodesAtLevel(NTree root, int level) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (level == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int x = nodesAtLevel(root->firstChild, level - 1);
    int y = nodesAtLevel(root->nextSibling, level - 1);

    return x + y + 1; //add 1 for current node
}
```

This should update the value after every recursion, unlike your current code.